# How to convert key value pairs i a text file into a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
3 : 124wr332::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img21.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::Top of:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img22.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::Gastric Antrum:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Patient MRN:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img23.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::Gastroscopy (OGD)::::::::Image label:::Other place:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::07/05/2018 13:25:45::::::::::Page 2::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img16.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::2nd part:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment:::Lovely:&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

But i'd like it to be in a dataframe where the column label is whatever the key is as defined as the label occurring before three :'s as follows:

```
Ident    img DateOfProcedure ProcedurePerformed ImageLabel ImageComment
123456A  21   2018-03-01      A thingy          Top of
123456A  22   2018-03-01      A thingy          Other place
123456A  23   2018-03-01      A thingy          2nd part       Lovely
```

Ive tried to use `a <- strsplit(as.character(my$key_value), ":::")` but it gives me key-value pairs on different rows whereas I want the key to be the column name as per above

Answer (score 0):

`splitstackshape` package is what you need. See example below:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(tidyverse)

x <- '3 : 124wr332::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img21.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::Top of:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img22.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::Gastric Antrum:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Patient MRN:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img23.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::Gastroscopy (OGD)::::::::Image label:::Other place:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment::::&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::07/05/2018 13:25:45::::::::::Page 2::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Ident:::123456A::::::::::::::::img src="Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img16.jpg" width="152" height="99" alt="":::::::::Date of procedure:::2018-03-01::::::::Procedure Performed:::A thingy::::::::Image label:::2nd part:::::::::::::::::::Image Comment:::Lovely:&nbsp;::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'

data.frame(col = x) %>% 
splitstackshape::cSplit(splitCols = "col", sep = ":::") %>% 
    glimpse
```

Comment: Sorry @cephalopod this doesn't seem to give the intended answer. Should I be providing the column headers as they appear in the text?